# Javascript Electron Menu open app window from Menu template file

Tags: javascript, electron

In my Electron App, I can created a Menu template at an external local file and called it menuTemplate.js

The menu works find but I want to be able to open a local file from it, for example about.html

I've tried *'window.open('url here')'* but it doesn't understand window ...

Here is the template:

```
module.exports = [
  {
    label: 'Electron',
    submenu: [
      {label: 'Item 1'},
      {label: 'Item 2'}
    ]
  },
  {
    label: 'Actions',
    submenu: [
      {label: 'Action 1'},
      {label: 'Action 2'},
      {label: 'Action 3'},
      {role: 'toggledevtools'},
      {label: 'ClickMe', click () { window.open('url here'); } }
    ]
  }
]
```

I've tried ***shell.openExternal*** and it works but I cannot get an app window to open from here.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is a good idea to separate a template like this into a separate file, you cannot  access the scope of the original file there. To solve this problem you have to bring your window from your mainfile (assumed to be called `main.js`) into your `menuTemplate.js`.

You could do this for example by creating a method that builds the template on execution. It could look something like this:

`menuTemplate.js`

```
module.exports = function(window){
    return [
      {
        label: 'Electron',
        submenu: [
          {label: 'Item 1'},
          {label: 'Item 2'}
        ]
      },
      {
        label: 'Actions',
        submenu: [
          {label: 'Action 1'},
          {label: 'Action 2'},
          {label: 'Action 3'},
          {role: 'toggledevtools'},
          {label: 'ClickMe', click () { window.open('url here'); } }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

Now when loading the template in `main.js` you do not do something like

`const template = require('menuTemplate')`

but something like

`const template = require('menuTemplate')(window)`,

with "window" being the name of your window variable.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

```
    label: 'General',
    submenu: [
      {label: 'Unidades',          
      click () {   mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, './app/fixed_footer.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true

      })); }
```